# Comparing two MGFs

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose I have two MGFs given by

$MGF_1 = e^{-2 (p-1) p x^2}$

and

$MGF_2 = e^{8 (p-1)^2 p^2 x^2}$.

Is there an accepted way to compare the corresponding probability distributions to obtain a metric for similarity?

(How similar are the probability distributions in this case?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your MGF's indicate the underlying distributions are Gaussian, with mean $0$, and variance in terms of $p$ (lazy to check MGF table).

Once you do this, you'd have $P_1:N(0,\sigma_1^2)$ and $P_2:N(0,\sigma_2^2)$. Now, you can compare them, one metric would be to measure the total variation (TV divergence between them). Another, would be Kullback-Leibler. In general, you can use any $f$-divergence.

Comment: Are you sure they both are Gaussian?

Comment: If you don't like the table in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) then how about Eq.(17) of [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDistribution.html)? You can find this in most textbooks, or just calculate it yourself (it's pretty easy).

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin The two MGFs are equal when p = 0.5 and p = 1. If p sufficiently captured variance, and we are dealing with two Gaussians, then I would guess that other values of p would make these MGFs equal too. Can you explain that?